# Regex - Integer Number with or without a single negative sign

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to create a regex for a number that can optionally be preceded by a single '-'.

What I have so far is: `"-?\\d+"` (double backslash to escape the '\' in C#)

The problem is this also matches `--123`. I want that there can only be a single negative symbol at the beginning.

Comment: That depends a bit; Are you trying to validate a single number, or extract all numbers in some text?

Answer (score 1):

If you are validating that a string contains a number and nothing else, i.e. that a string contains an optional hyphen followed by some digits then you can anchor the pattern to the start and the end of the string, thus `^-?\d+$`.

Another way of validating that the string looks like a possibly negative number is to parse it as a integer with `int.Parse` or `int.TryParse` methods. If the parse succeeds then you have a valid number that matches the wanted pattern. Numbers that are too big (either positive or negative) for an integer will fail to parse. Bigger numbers can be accepted with the `long.Parse` and `long.TryParse` methods. There is also a `BigInteger` class for arbitrarily large numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
"(?:(?<!-)-)?\\d+"
```

**Explanation**

```
(?<!)
```

This is a [negative lookbehind assertion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx#Grouping%20Constructs) which says this "must not be preceeeded by". It's also zero-width so doesn't consume anything.

```
(?:)
```

This is a [non-capturing group](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx#Grouping%20Constructs) since we don't want to capture what it matches. The group is there for logic only so capturing is switched off.

Answer (score 0):

How about just parsing it to an `int` in C#

```
int num;
bool success = int.TryParse(val, out num);
```

Leave regex until you really need it...